# Image of holomorphic function on punctured compact Riemann Surface is Dense

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

*Let $M$ be a compact Riemann surface and $S \subset M$ is discrete. Suppose $f: M \setminus S \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic and nonconstant. Show that the image of $M \setminus S$ under $f$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.*

So if we try contradiction, we assume $f(M \setminus S)$ isn't dense in $\mathbb{C}$, then there exists an neighborhood $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ that does not intersect $f(M \setminus S)$. The problem hints that $S$ must then contain poles, but I don't see how this follows? Also I don't know how you could get a contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

If it's not dense, e.g. if $a\in\mathbb C$ is not in the closure of the image, then $1/(f-a)$ is holomorphic on $M\backslash S$ and bounded, so by removable singularity thm we can extend $1/(f-a)$ to a holomorphic (and still bounded) function on $M$, but its image is both compact and open.

Comment: I see that there is a neighbourhood on which 1/(f-a) will be bounded, and so we can extend 1/(f-a) to the point that maps to a, does that mean we can extend the function f itself? Also, say the closure of f(M\S) is the closed bottom half plane, could we use the above method to extend to every single point in the top half-plane?

Comment: @user82235 I'm extending $1/(f-a)$ to $M$ and get a contradiction (as you needed); I don't understand 'to the point that maps to $a$'. For your second question - it can't happen.

Comment: Oh thanks! I was thinking about it in the wrong way. The only remaining bit I have concern with is: If there is a $p \in S$ such that $f(p) = a$, why is $1/(f-a)$ holomorphically extendable to p? After all, it's not bounded in any neighbourhood of p, so the removable singularity theorem shouldn't apply, right?

Comment: OR: Since $U$ is an open set that $f$ misses, it is uncountably big. So we are "allowed" to pick an $a \in U$ such that no points in $S$ map to $a$, and thus have no need to worry about removable singularities? (Sorry for the new comment, I was too late to edit the previous one)

Comment: @user82235:$f$ is defined on $M\backslash S$. We suppose that $a$ is such that it has a neighbourhood $U\ni a$ such that $U\cap f(M\backslash S)=\emptyset$. $f$ is not defined on entire $M$, but even if it were (and were at least continuous) then it couldn't have $a$ as a value (but I'm not using it). The only thing used is that $1/(f-a)$, again defined on $M\backslash S$, is bounded, so we can apply Riemann's removable sigluarity thm (around every point of $S$).

Comment: I think it is quite important that $f$ even defined on entire $M$ cannot have $a$ as a value. If it has $a$ as a value, then $1/(f-a)$, defined on $M\setminus S$, will not be bounded, since if $p \in S$ and the extended function $f$ maps $p$ to $a$, then the limit of $1/(f-a)$ in $M \setminus S$ as we approach $p$ will be unbounded. However, if no points in $S$ map to $a$, then and only then will $1/(f-a)$ be bounded in $M \setminus S$. So I'm wondering why $f$ defined on entire $M$ still cannot have $a$ as a value?

Comment: @user82235 how could it have $a$ as a value if $f|_{M\backslash S}$  has no values in $U$? Please reread my proof; I don't think there is anything missing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10885/discussion-between-user82235-and-user8268)